# pthread_key_create destructor not getting called

Tags: c++, pthreads, shutdown, thread-specific-storage

As per [pthread_key_create](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_key_create/) man page we can associate a destructor to be called at thread shut down. My problem is that the destructor function I have registered is not being called. Gist of my code is as follows.

```
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t tls_init_flag = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void destructor(void *t) {
  // thread local data structure clean up code here, which is not getting called
}

void create_key() {
  pthread_key_create(&key, destructor);
}

// This will be called from every thread
void set_thread_specific() {

  ts = new ts_stack; // Thread local data structure

  pthread_once(&tls_init_flag, create_key);
  pthread_setspecific(key, ts);
}
```

Any idea what might prevent this destructor being called? I am also using atexit() at moment to do some cleanup in the main thread. Is there any chance that is interfering with destructor function being called? I tried removing that as well. Still didn't work though. Also I am not clear if I should handle the main thread as a separate case with atexit. (It's a must to use atexit by the way, since I need to do some application specific cleanup at application exit)

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.

The main thread exits (by returning or calling `exit()`), and that doesn't use `pthread_exit()`. POSIX documents `pthread_exit` calling the thread-specific destructors.

You could add `pthread_exit()` at the end of `main`. Alternatively, you can use `atexit` to do your destruction. In that case, it would be clean to set the thread-specific value to `NULL` so in case the `pthread_exit` was invoked, the destruction wouldn't happen twice for that key.

**UPDATE** Actually, I've solved my immediate worries by simply adding this to my global unit test setup function:

```
::atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });
```

So, in context of my global fixture class `MyConfig`:

```
struct MyConfig {
    MyConfig()   {
        GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;
        ::atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });
    }
    ~MyConfig()  { google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary(); }
};
```

Some of the references used:

- http://www.resolvinghere.com/sof/6357154.shtml
- https://sourceware.org/ml/pthreads-win32/2008/msg00007.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_exit.html

---

PS. Of course c++11 [introduced `<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) so you have better and more portable primitves to work with.

Comment: Added a concise workaround that I can't currently think of having major downsides: `::atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });`

Comment: Note that POSIX states *The functions registered by a call to atexit() must return to ensure that all registered functions are called*. So if you use `pthread_exit()` in an atexit-registered function, any remaining functions on the atexit stack may not be called.

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer very good point. I'll have to revisit this thought when I touch the code again

Answer (score 2):

It's already in sehe's answer, just to present the key points in a compact way:

- `pthread_key_create()` destructor calls are triggered by a call to `pthread_exit()`.
- If the start routine of a thread returns, the behaviour is as if `pthread_exit()` was called (i. e., destructor calls are triggered).
- *However*, if `main()` returns, the behaviour is as if `exit()` was called — no destructor calls are triggered.

This is explained in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html. See also C++17 6.6.1p5 or C11 5.1.2.2.3p1.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick test and the only thing I changed was moving the `create_key` call of yours outside of the `set_thread_specific`.

That is, I called it within the main thread.

I then saw my destroy get called when the thread routine exited.

Answer (score 0):

I call **destructor()** manually at the end of **main()**:

```
void * ThreadData = NULL;

if ((ThreadData = pthread_getspecific(key)) != NULL)
        destructor(ThreadData);
```

Of course **key** should be properly initialized earlier in **main()** code.
PS. Calling **Pthread_Exit()** at the end to **main()** seems to hang entire application...

Answer (score 0):

Your initial thought of handling the main thread as a separate case with atexit worked best for me.

Be ware that pthread_exit(0) overwrites the exit value of the process.  For example, the following program will exit with status of zero even though main() returns with number three:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class ts_stack {
public:
  ts_stack () {
    printf ("init\n");
  }
  ~ts_stack () {
    printf ("done\n");
  }
};

static void cleanup (void);

static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t tls_init_flag = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void destructor(void *t) {
  // thread local data structure clean up code here, which is not getting called
  delete (ts_stack*) t;
}

void create_key() {
  pthread_key_create(&key, destructor);
  atexit(cleanup);
}

// This will be called from every thread
void set_thread_specific() {
  ts_stack *ts = new ts_stack (); // Thread local data structure

  pthread_once(&tls_init_flag, create_key);
  pthread_setspecific(key, ts);
}

static void cleanup (void) {
  pthread_exit(0); // <-- Calls destructor but sets exit status to zero as a side effect!
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  set_thread_specific();
  return 3; // Attempt to exit with status of 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue as yours: `pthread_setspecific` sets a key, but the destructor never gets called. To fix it we simply switched to `thread_local` in C++. You could also do something like if that change is too complicated:

For example, assume you have some class `ThreadData` that you want some action to be done on when the thread finishes execution. You define the destructor something on these lines:

```
void destroy_my_data(ThreadlData* t) {
   delete t;
}
```

When your thread starts, you allocate memory for `ThreadData*` instance and assign a destructor to it like this:

```
ThreadData* my_data = new ThreadData;
thread_local ThreadLocalDestructor<ThreadData> tld;
tld.SetDestructorData(my_data, destroy_my_data);
pthread_setspecific(key, my_data)
```

Notice that `ThreadLocalDestructor` is defined as thread_local. We rely on C++11 mechanism that when the thread exits, the destructor of `ThreadLocalDestructor` will be automatically called, and `~ThreadLocalDestructor` is implemented to call function `destroy_my_data`.

Here is the implementation of ThreadLocalDestructor:

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadLocalDestructor
{
public:
    ThreadLocalDestructor() : m_destr_func(nullptr), m_destr_data(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~ThreadLocalDestructor()
    {
        if (m_destr_func) {
            m_destr_func(m_destr_data);
        }
    }
    void SetDestructorData(void (*destr_func)(T*), T* destr_data)
    {
        m_destr_data = destr_data;
        m_destr_func = destr_func;
    }

private:
    void (*m_destr_func)(T*);
    T* m_destr_data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers propose to make a call to `pthread_exit()`, but by doing so the main thread does not call `exit()` or `return`, and therefore the functions registered with `atexit()` are not called.

Maybe this will help you:

```c
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t tls_init_flag = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void destructor(void *t) {
  // thread local data structure clean up code here, which is not getting called
}

void cleanup(void) {
  ts = pthread_getspecific(key);
  if (ts != NULL) {                   // if "main" thread has specific data
    destructor(ts);                   // destroy data
    pthread_setspecific(key, NULL);   // unset specific data
  }

  // if key is in a library module (so set_thread_specific is too)
  // delete key at program exit.
  // pthread_key_delete(key);
}

void create_key() {
  pthread_key_create(&key, destructor);
  atexit(cleanup);                    // register cleanup function for "main" thread.
}

// This will be called from every thread
void set_thread_specific() {

  ts = new ts_stack; // Thread local data structure

  pthread_once(&tls_init_flag, create_key);
  pthread_setspecific(key, ts);
}
```