# Why is the destructor passed in through pthread_key_create being called only by children thread but the main thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Code:

http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/threads/strerror_tsd.c

```
static void                         /* Free thread-specific data buffer */
destructor(void *buf)
{
    free(buf);
}

static void                         /* One-time key creation function */
createKey(void)
{
    int s;

    /* Allocate a unique thread-specific data key and save the address
       of the destructor for thread-specific data buffers */

    s = pthread_key_create(&strerrorKey, destructor);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_key_create");
}

char *
strerror(int err)
{
    int s;
    char *buf;

    /* Make first caller allocate key for thread-specific data */

    s = pthread_once(&once, createKey);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_once");

    buf = pthread_getspecific(strerrorKey);
    if (buf == NULL) {          /* If first call from this thread, allocate
                                   buffer for thread, and save its location */
        buf = malloc(MAX_ERROR_LEN);
        if (buf == NULL)
            errExit("malloc");

        s = pthread_setspecific(strerrorKey, buf);
        if (s != 0)
            errExitEN(s, "pthread_setspecific");
    }

    if (err < 0 || err >= _sys_nerr || _sys_errlist[err] == NULL) {
        snprintf(buf, MAX_ERROR_LEN, "Unknown error %d", err);
    } else {
        strncpy(buf, _sys_errlist[err], MAX_ERROR_LEN - 1);
        buf[MAX_ERROR_LEN - 1] = '\0';          /* Ensure null termination */
    }

    return buf;
}
```

http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/threads/strerror_test.c

```
static void *
threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    char *str;

    printf("Other thread about to call strerror()\n");
    str = strerror(EPERM);
    printf("Other thread: str (%p) = %s\n", str, str);

    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t;
    int s;
    char *str;

    str = strerror(EINVAL);
    printf("Main thread has called strerror()\n");

    s = pthread_create(&t, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_create");

    s = pthread_join(t, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_join");

    /* If strerror() is not thread-safe, then the output of this printf() be
       the same as that produced by the analogous printf() in threadFunc() */

    printf("Main thread:  str (%p) = %s\n", str, str);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Question:

```
int pthread_key_create(pthread_key_t *key, void (destructor)(void *));
```

The implementation of `strerror` uses thread-specific data. Upon termination of a thread that has a non-NULL value associated with key, the
destructor function is automatically invoked by the Pthreads API and given that
value as its argument. Based on my testing, the main thread calling to `strerror` will NOT trigger the `destructor` but the child thread will. I would like to know why?

Thank you

Comment: Title unclear. destructor not called in main thread?

Comment: when I said destructor, I mean the function passed to pthread_key_create(&strerrorKey, destructor)

Comment: @q0987, I think Tony's question was about the intended meaning of "but the main thread".  And if even if not, that's what *I* want to know.

Comment: My second question would be about why you have any expectation that the destructor function would *ever* be called, and especially why you expect that a call to `strerror()` would produce such an effect.  Neither your `main()` nor your `threadFunc()` appears to do anything that would have that result, whether directly or indirectly.  I would expect a member with your rep to know very well that we need a [mre], and how to prepare a good one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thats exactly what I was asking.

Comment: I have updated my original question and hopefully, I addressed all your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_key_t key;

void destroy(void *data) 
{
  fprintf(stderr, "==> %s on thread %lu with argument %p\n", __func__, pthread_self(), data);
}

void *target(void *data)
{
  // comment out the following line and destroy will not be called from child thread
  pthread_setspecific(key, target);

  fprintf(stderr, "%s set key to %p on thread %lu\n", __func__, pthread_getspecific(key), pthread_self());
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s is on thread %lu\n", __func__, pthread_self());

  pthread_key_create(&key, destroy);
  pthread_setspecific(key, main);

  fprintf(stderr, "%s set key to %p\n", __func__, pthread_getspecific(key));

  pthread_t child;
  pthread_create(&child, NULL, target, NULL);

  fprintf(stderr, "main thread created thread %lu\n",  child);

  pthread_join(child, NULL);

  fprintf(stderr, "main thread joined child\n");

  // comment out the following line and destroy will not be called from main thread
  pthread_exit(main);
  return 0;
}
```

According to the man page for [pthread_key_create](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html)

> At thread exit, if a key value has a non-NULL destructor pointer, and the thread has a non-NULL value associated with that key, the value of the key is set to NULL, and then the function pointed to is called with the previously associated value as its sole argument.

In both the question code and the simplified example, each thread has set the key to a non-NULL value, so it seems like the destructor should be called on each thread.

But the way the main thread exits by default, the key specific destructors are not called.  See [pthread_create man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) and [question 24521968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521968/pthread-key-create-destructor-not-getting-called).  Calling pthread_exit() at the end of main will invoke the destructor.